# Springboot and Mongo containers are not connecting

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker, containers

I'm running 2 containers on my local machine using docker compose. The first one is mongo container and the second is spring boot application.

This is my spring boot's Dockerfile

```
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/app.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
RUN bash -c "touch /app.jar"
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo/test", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

This is my spring boot's application properties

```
# mongodb configuration0
dockerspring.data.mongodb.uri= mongodb://mongo:27000/test
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services: 

  level-2-springboot:
    image: level-2:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: level_2_microservice
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    working_dir: /tmp
    depends_on: 
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    ports: 
      - 27000:27017
    restart: always
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.yash</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-sync-ms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-sync</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>            
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

I execute this to create image for my spring boot app

`docker build -t level-2 .`

After I see my image, I execute `docker-compose up` and they work just fine no error

[image]

Here is the containers running

[image]

But when i do a POST or GET request to `localhost:8081/api/employees/` or `localhost:8080/api/employees/` I'd get this message from Postman

> Could not get any response

Below is my project structure

[image]

If I run the app on eclipse and mongo manually and do POST/GET request, I'd get 201 OK, but when I do it using docker in containers, they dont talk to each other. Anyone know whats causing this?

Comment: Try to run your `app.jar` outside docker container, make sure it's packaged correctly

Comment: did you mean to bring docker-compose.yml outside spring sync and do docker-compose up outside spring sync?

Comment: Could not get any response sounds like an issue with your @Controller class in the first place

Comment: @Gewure thats what i thought, but when I do it without container and docker (meaning running it manually as a spring boot app) it works no problem, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I've consulted the internet and i think i got what you need.

> The question that follows is “how does our service container talk to
>   the Mongo container?” For that, we get into **container linking**.
>   When you run a container, you can pass an optional `–link` parameter,
>   specifying the running container *name* that the new container needs to
>   be able to communicate with.
>
> So with our command

```
docker run -P -d --name employee --link mongodb microservicedemo/employee
```

> we fire up our new container image, exposing its ports (-P) in the background
>   (-d), naming it employee (–name), and telling it to link to the
>   container named “mongodb” (–link). Linking these does the following:
>
> Creates a hosts file entry in the employee container pointing at the
>   running location of the MongoDB container Inserts a number of
>   environment variables in the employee container to assist with any
>   other programmatic access needed.
>
> To see them run: `docker exec employee bash -c 'env |grep MONGODB'` 
>   Allows containers to communicate directly over ports exposed, so there is no need to
>   worry about the hose machine part mapping.

see:
https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/building-a-microservice-architecture-with-spring-boot-and-docker-part-iii

https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/building-a-microservice-architecture-with-spring-boot-and-docker-part-ii

Comment: if i were to run this <docker run -P -d --name employee --link mongodb microservicedemo/employee> wouldnt it defeat the purpose of using docker compose?

Answer (score 0):

This: 
`# mongodb configuration0
dockerspring.data.mongodb.uri= mongodb://mongo:27000/test`

Should be: 
`# mongodb configuration0
dockerspring.data.mongodb.uri= mongodb://mongo:27017/test`

The two services in your docker-compose.yml expose Ports 8081 and 27000 to the **host machine**. 
But **inside the network created by docker-compose** they expose Ports 8080 and 27017.
As your Mongo-Container runs in the docker-compose network, it has to use Port 27017 to connect to the database.

Comment: I changed the uri but it still doesnt work when doing post or get requests